# Count times an expression is true in awk.

Tags: text-processing, awk

In unix/awk code

Essentially, I need to iterate through the file (data1.txt) and count the number of times the substr($0,29,2) of each line of the file == "04".

data1.txt:

```
6597243042 20160305001100003140152852153019000127000200
6597243042 20160305001100003140170306190306020000000200
6597243042 20160305001100003140170552190552020000000200
6597243042 20160305001100003140201430201543000113000400
6592311319 20160305041100003460072719072839000120001200
6592311319 20160305041100003460072927072952000025001200
```

In this case only 2 lines of the file (data1.txt) fulfill the condition (substr($0,29,2)=="04")

I am stuck at finding a way to do so

Below is my unix/awk code

```
Filename="def"
file="data1.txt"
#awk '{count1=0}'
while IFS= read line
do

   awk '{ if (substr($0,29,2)=="04") {print substr($0,29,4)}}' 

done <"$file"
```

How can I count this?

Comment: None of the lines in your text file match such condition. Beside, you're not reading `$line` in the `while` loop. And the loop wouldn't be needed either, use just AWK: `awk 'substr($0,29,2)=="04" {print}' file` (again, in your file no line matches such condition).

Comment: I disagree on moving to SO, code inside awk have beed discussed here, beside OP is a bit about feeding awk with a file.

Answer (score 4):

Another approach (thanks to Archemar + kos for avoiding use of deprecated `egrep` and using `-c`)

```
grep -cE '^.{28}04' data1.txt
```

Comment: Also `egrep` and company (`fgrep`, `rgrep`) are deprecated. When possible use `grep -E`.

Answer (score 3):

simply try

```
awk 'BEGIN { count = 0 ;} substr($0,29,2) == "04" { count++ ; } END { print count ;}' files
```

where

- `substr($0,29,2) == "04"` search fo condition
- `{ count++ ; }`  if found increase count
- `END` at the end
- `{ print count ;}` print it.

edit:

- `count=0` thanks to @steeldriver

awk command line can be entered as below for readability.

```
awk 'BEGIN { count = 0 ;} 
     substr($0,29,2) == "04" { count++ ; } 
     END { print count ;}' files
```

Comment: Alternately, `END{print +count}`will print 0 for a zero count without the need for initialization